# TRegExpr(exec): Loop Stack Exceeded;

Tags: regex, stack-overflow, pascal

I have program in pascal that searches for defined types using regex.
Here is my regex: `type\s((([\w\d]+?=(([\w\d^():]+?;)|(record.*?end;)))+?)+)`

I'm getting that error on this input string:

```
type ElementListyWsk=^ElementListy;ElementListy=record wskaznik:pointer;nstElement:ElementListyWsk;end;OperacjaNaTypiePtr=procedure(cos:pointer);StalaWsk=^Stala;Stala=record nazwa:string;wartosc:string;end;ZmiennaWsk=^Zmienna;Zmienna=record nazwa:string;typ:string;end;TypWsk=^Typ;Typ=record nazwa:string;definicja:string;end;ProceduraWsk=^Procedura;Procedura=record deklaracja:string;stale:ElementListyWsk;zmienne:ElementListyWsk;typy:ElementListyWsk;end;
```

While I'm not getting any error on shorter string. Next strign is just shorten part of the above one:

```
type OperacjaNaTypiePtr=procedure(cos:pointer);StalaWsk=^Stala;Stala=record nazwa:string;wartosc:string;end;ZmiennaWsk=^Zmienna;Zmienna=record nazwa:string;typ:string;end;TypWsk=^Typ;Typ=record nazwa:string;definicja:string;end;ProceduraWsk=^Procedura;Procedura=record deklaracja:string;stale:ElementListyWsk;zmienne:ElementListyWsk;typy:ElementListyWsk;end;
```

Why I'm getting that error?
If you need more information just ask for it.

Comment: To debug regex, maybe it is useful to name the regex implementation that you are using?

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort TRegExpr from Lazaruz 1.02. I rally need to get that one done.